# Understanding Lemma: $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty} \leq \left|f(a) \right| + V_{a}^{b} f$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

I'm learning about functions of bounded variations and need help to understand the proof of this lemma:

> **Lemma.** *If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of bounded variation, then f is also bounded and satisfies $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty} \leq \left|f(a) \right| + V_{a}^{b} f$.*
>
> **Proof.** Let $a \leq x \leq b$, and set $P = \{a, x, b\}$. Then $\left| f(x) - f(a) \right| \leq V(f, P) \leq V_{a}^{b} f$. Consequently, $\underbrace{\left| f(x) \right| \leq \left| f(a) \right| + V_{a}^{b} f}_{(1)}$.

In inequality (1) I don't understand how we're able to break the absolute value.

Also, I'm a little confused by the symbol $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty}$. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the function, also called the essential supremum. It is the largest (more precisely, the supremum of) number $\alpha$ for which $\{x : |f(x)| > \alpha\}$ has positive measure. For a continuous function on a compact set, it coincides with the maximum.

---

As far as the inequality, it appears to be a typo and one $x$ ought to be an $a$. It follows from the (reverse) triangle inequality:

$$|f(x)| - |f(a)| \le |f(x) - f(a)| \le ...$$

One way to see the first inequality is to apply the usual triangle inequality to $f(x) = f(x) - f(a) + f(a)$.

The correct statement of the lemma should actually be

$$\|f\|_{\infty} \le |f(a)| + V_{a}^b f$$

Comment: You are correct about the typo, thanks for noticing me. Just so I'm sure I'm not making any mistakes, applying the *Triangle Inequality* as you proposed we have $\left|f(x) \right| = \left|f(x) - f(a) + f(a)\right| \leq \left|f(x) - f(a) \right| + \left| f(a) \right| \implies \left|f(x) \right| - \left| f(a) \right| \leq \left|f(x) - f(a) \right|$. Is that correct? I also have one more question : later in the chapter the author use the symbol $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{BV}$. What is the difference with $\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct application. As far as $\|f\|_{BV}$, the definition I'm familiar with is $$\|f\|_{BV} = \|f\|_1 + V_a^b f$$ This involves a mix of the average value of $f$ and how choppy $f$ looks locally.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation.

Comment: @VonKar You're very welcome.